# vala logical operations don't work

Tags: if-statement, logical-operators, vala

I'm making a program and I am making an 'if' statement, which I want to have many boolean expresions altogether using 'or' between them. But I can't make out how. My code:

```
if (input == "hello"* || input == "hi"*) {
        output = "Hi!";
};
```

and the error I get:

```
Roxanne.vala:33.31-33.32: error: syntax error, expected identifier
        if (input == "hello"* || input == "hi"*) {
                              ^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There's a `*` after the strings `"hello"` and `"hi"`. The compiler thinks you are trying to do multiplication.

Comment: Is that the one braking the code? I use them as wildcards. Is there a replacement?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  The only language I can think of that supports wildcards in a vaugely similar manner to what you wrote is shell.  Try `input.has_prefix("hello") || input.has_prefix("hi")`.